# using Google Map Geolocation API Service in ASP.net C#

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I want to get the user current location using Google Map Geolocation API Service and using the following code but the when i run the code it does not show the map with the location. Please give any suggestions.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>Get User Current Location using Google Map Geolocation API Service in asp.net website</title>
<style type="text/css">
html { height: 100% }
body { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0 }
#map_canvas { height: 100% }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyC6v5-2uaq_wusHDktM9ILcqIrlPtnZgEk&sensor=false"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&libraries=places"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success);
    } else {
        alert("Geo Location is not supported on your current browser!");
    }
    function success(position) {
        var latitude = position.coords.latitude;
        var longitude = position.coords.longitude;
        var city = position.coords.locality;
        var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude);
        var myOptions = {
            center: myLatlng,
            zoom: 12,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: myLatlng,
            title: "lat: " + latitude + " long: " + longitude
        });

        marker.setMap(map);
        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({ content: "<b>User Address</b><br/> Latitude:" + latitude + "<br /> Longitude:" + longitude + "" });
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
   <div id="map_canvas" style="width: 500px; height: 400px"></div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Why have you added twice `google.maps`.
**1:** `<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyC6v5-2uaq_wusHDktM9ILcqIrlPtnZgEk&sensor=false"></script>`
**2:** `<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&libraries=places"></script>`

Comment: I have used this link http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2013/01/show-user-current-location-on-google.html

Comment: After removing one of the library, the same issue is there

Comment: are you using `Chrome` ?
Have you errors in the console?

Comment: Yes i am using chrome and checked it on IE, No errors in console.

Comment: The code is working.
Did you authorize the site to get (know) your location.

Comment: Yes but it shows blank screen in chrome

Comment: So, in IE is working?

Comment: Just now i have checked in IE it is working

Comment: But it is not showing the exact location. Why it is so..

Comment: well the location is calculated by the browser and some internet sevice based in your IP address. Is not a GPS location using a real GPS sensor.

Comment: Did my answer below and the comments above help you?

Comment: In Google Chrome it is not working but in other browsers like firefox and IE it is working. I think it might be some security issues in Chrome, that is preventing access to the system location, but thanks for your help.

Comment: It's what I said in my answer below ;)

Comment: I edited my answer to explain how to remove the blocked sites. Let me know if this work for you.

Comment: It didn't worked, settings are same as yours, i have added images in my question, so that it is clear from that...

Answer (score 0):

I have used exactly your code and is working.
Make sure when you see this message in *Chrome*
You click in **Allow**

[image: Authorize site to get location]

If you already **Denied** your site you have to remove it from the unauthorized list (or change your port).

To do so:

Go to google settings and search for *Privacy*:

[image: Privacy Settings]

Click in *Content settings...* button and search the Location area:

[image: Content settings]

Click sur *Manage exceptions...* button, then remove your blocked site(s) :

[image: location exceptions]

---

My result with your code is this:

[image: The restult]

Your code (which I'm exactly using):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>Get User Current Location using Google Map Geolocation API Service in asp.net website</title>
<style type="text/css">
html { height: 100% }
body { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0 }
#map_canvas { height: 100% }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyC6v5-2uaq_wusHDktM9ILcqIrlPtnZgEk&sensor=false"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&libraries=places"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success);
    } else {
        alert("Geo Location is not supported on your current browser!");
    }
    function success(position) {
        var latitude = position.coords.latitude;
        var longitude = position.coords.longitude;
        var city = position.coords.locality;
        var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude);
        var myOptions = {
            center: myLatlng,
            zoom: 12,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: myLatlng,
            title: "lat: " + latitude + " long: " + longitude
        });

        marker.setMap(map);
        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({ content: "<b>User Address</b><br/> Latitude:" + latitude + "<br /> Longitude:" + longitude + "" });
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
   <div id="map_canvas" style="width: 500px; height: 400px"></div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```